# Retrofit Unauthorized message

Tags: android

This is my interface for retrofit

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json"
})
@GET("api/services/app/Profile/GetCurrentUserProfileForEdit")
Call<GetUserProfile> getUserProfile(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
Call<GetUserProfile> call = guardRestManager.getServices().getUserProfile("Bearer"+"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.jnCOhK3Iu1_x5XBP9Kd5oMCYj2iDrElLA8baRYX1FpM");
```

In postman it gives the right response. But in my application it gives me:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://192.168.0.121:503/api/services/app/Profile/GetCurrentUserProfileForEdit}

Answer (score 1):

Add space after Bearer.
Replace this:

("Bearer"+"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.jnCOhK3Iu1_x5XBP9Kd5oMCYj2iDrElLA8baRYX1FpM")

with:

("Bearer "+"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.jnCOhK3Iu1_x5XBP9Kd5oMCYj2iDrElLA8baRYX1FpM")

There should be a single space between bearer and token

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the problem before. The solution is to add space between the **Token type(Bearer)** and the **Token**.

Comment: you need to add some more explanation to your answer.